# what does '?.' mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-operator

I do know the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

but using '?' without colon that's unusual to me

**Here is an example:**

`path?.forEach(id => checkID(id));`

Comment: check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: See also: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780)

Comment: See the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).